# Virtual Keyboard appears even when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, keyboard

I am building an app in Phonegap and the problem I am facing has turned up only after testing the product. My problem is as follows:

I have a login page with 2 input fields and a login button. When the input fields are clicked the virtual keyboard on my device displays correctly. The problem is when the input fields are empty and the button is clicked. Along with an error message, the keyboard also appears and fades when the done button on the alert is clicked.

How do I stop the keyboard from appearing along with the error message?

**EDITED:**

**HTML**

```
<section data-role="page" id="start" data-enhance="false">
    <div data-role="content">
        <br>
        <br>
        <div align="right">
            <a href="#" id="help" data-role="button">
                <img src="./img/help-icon.png" style="margin-right: 11px;" />
            </a>
        </div>

        <div align="center">
            <img src="./img/Logo login screen.png" height="200" width="170" />
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>
        <form id="loginForm" align="center" data-ajax="false">
            <div id="user" align="center">
                <input class="amazeFont" type="text" id="accessKey" Placeholder="Access Key (20 characters)" size="30" maxlength="128" tabindex="1" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]" height="100" />
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="pass" align="center">
                <input class="amazeFont" type="password" id="secretKey" Placeholder="Secret Key (40 characters)" size="30" maxlength="1024" autocomplete="on" tabindex="2" data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]" />
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <center>
                <button type="button" id="submitButton">Login</button>
            </center>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
accKey = $("#accessKey").val();
secKey = $("#secretKey").val();

if (empty(accKey)) {
   navigator.notification.alert(
      "AccessKey and SecretKey Combination Incorrect or One of the fields is empty! Please check and Retry!",
      function(){},
      "Key Mismatch",
      "Done");
  //alert("AccessKey and SecretAccessKey fields are empty! Please enter values and Retry!");
   $("#accessKey").focus();
  } else {
    if (empty(secKey)) {
       navigator.notification.alert(
        "AccessKey and SecretKey Combination Incorrect or One of the fields is empty! Please check and Retry!",
        function(){},
        "Key Mismatch",
        "Done");
       // alert("AccessKey and SecretAccessKey fields are empty! Please enter values and Retry!");
       $("#accessKey").focus();
    } else {
        //DO SOMETHING;
  }
}
```

Comment: ... should we guess your code? This isn't a normal behaviour so there must be a mistake inside your code or in your workflow. An `alert` will never trigger the virtual keyboard.

And, for clearness, you mean, that when someone clicks on the login button, and Username/Password are empty, the keyboard appears?

Comment: Yes. When the Username/Password are empty and some clicks on the login button, the keyboard appears. Sorry for not posting my code. Please see my edit.